abnormal behaviour with preserving the elitism
I hope you are doing well.
I am writing a simple genetic algorithm in Java. However, I am encountering an issue with elitism. When I try to preserve the best individuals, I observe abnormal behavior in the results. Specifically, after a few iterations, the fitness values start from a higher value than the one preserved from the previous generation.
Could you please help me understand why this is happening?
As for following snippet
public class SphereFunction {

public static void main(String[] args) {
//        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
//            System.out.println("\n\n" + x + "\n\n\n");

        GeneticAlgorithm ga = new GeneticAlgorithm(100, 0.5, 0.85, 2, 5);

        Population population = ga.initPopulation(40);

        //Evaluate population
        ga.evalPopulation(population);

        //Initiate Elite population
        Population elite = ga.initElitismPopulation(population);
        //ga.elitismPopulation(population, elite);

        int generation = 0;


        while (!ga.isTerminationConditionMet(generation, 75)) {
            // Print fittest individual from population
            //System.out.println("Best solution: " + population.getFittest(population.size() - 1).getFitness() + ", " + population.getFittest(population.size() - 2).getFitness());

            /* Preserve Elitism **/
            ga.elitismPopulation(population, elite);
            ga.updatePopulationWithElite(population, elite);

            /* crossover **/
            //population = ga.sirCrossover(population);
            population = ga.sirMultiPointCrossover(population);

            /* mutation **/
            population = ga.sirMutate(population);

            /* update population with preserve**/
            //ga.updatePopulationWithElite(population, elite);

            // Evaluate population
            ga.evalPopulation(population);


            generation++;


        }


        Population mergedPopulation = ga.mergePopulation(population, elite);

        System.out.println("\nFound solution in " + generation + " generations");
        System.out.println("Best Solution for (" + population.getFittest(population.size() - 1).getFitness() + ") " + population.getIndividual(population.size() - 1));
        //System.out.println("Worst Solution for (" + population.getIndividual(0).getFitness() + ") " + population.getIndividual(0));
//        System.out.println("Best Solution  for (" + population.getIndividual(population.size() - 1).getFitness() + ") " + population.getIndividual(population.size() - 1));
        System.out.println("Best Solution for merged population (" + mergedPopulation.getFittest(mergedPopulation.size() - 1).getFitness() + ") " + mergedPopulation.getIndividual(mergedPopulation.size() - 1));

    }
}

public class Individual {
    private int[] chromosome;
    private double fitness = -1;

    public Individual(int[] chromosome) {
        this.chromosome = chromosome;
    }



    public Individual(int chromosomeLength) {
        this.chromosome = new int[chromosomeLength];
        for (int gene = 0; gene < chromosomeLength; gene++) {
            if (0.5 < Math.random()) {
                this.setGene(gene, 1);
            } else {
                this.setGene(gene, 0);
            }
        }
    }



    public int[] getChromosome() {
        return this.chromosome;
    }

    public int getChromosomeLength() {
        return this.chromosome.length;
    }

    public void setGene(int offset, int gene) {
        this.chromosome[offset] = gene;
    }

    public int getGene(int offset) {
        return this.chromosome[offset];
    }

    public double getFitness() {
        return this.fitness;
    }

    public void setFitness(double fitness) {
        this.fitness = fitness;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String output = "";
        for (int gene = 0; gene < this.chromosome.length; gene++) {
            output += this.chromosome[gene];
        }
        return output;
    }
}




import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Random;

public class Population {
    private Individual population[];
    private double populationFitness = -1;

    public Population(int populationSize) {
        this.population = new Individual[populationSize];
    }

    public Population(int populationSize, int chromosomeLength) {
        this.population = new Individual[populationSize];
        for (int individualCount = 0; individualCount < populationSize; individualCount++) {
            Individual individual = new Individual(chromosomeLength);
            this.population[individualCount] = individual;
        }
    }

    public Individual[] getIndividuals() {
        return this.population;
    }

    public Individual getFittest(int offset) {
        Arrays.sort(this.population, new Comparator<Individual>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Individual o1, Individual o2) {
                if (o1.getFitness() > o2.getFitness()) {
                    return -1;
                } else if (o1.getFitness() < o2.getFitness()) {
                    return 1;
                }
                return 0;
            }
        });
        return this.population[offset];
    }

    public void setPopulationFitness(double fitness) {
        this.populationFitness = fitness;
    }

    public double getPopulationFitness() {
        return this.populationFitness;
    }


    public int size() {
        return this.population.length;
    }

    public Individual setIndividual(int offset, Individual individual) {
        return population[offset] = individual;
    }

    public Individual getIndividual(int offset) {
        return population[offset];
    }

    public void shuffle() {
        Random ran = new Random();
        for (int i = population.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {

            int index = ran.nextInt(i + 1);

            Individual a = population[index];
            //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a.getChromosome()) + " " + a.getFitness());

            population[index] = population[i];
            population[i] = a;
        }

    }

    public void sortPopulation() {
        Arrays.sort(this.population, (o1, o2) -> {
            if (o1.getFitness() > o2.getFitness()) {
                return -1;
            } else if (o1.getFitness() < o2.getFitness()) {
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        });
    }

    public void sortAscPopulation() {
        Arrays.sort(this.population, (o1, o2) -> {
            if (o1.getFitness() < o2.getFitness()) {
                return -1;
            } else if (o1.getFitness() > o2.getFitness()) {
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        });
    }
}




import java.util.Random;

public class GeneticAlgorithm {
    private int populationSize;
    private double mutationRate;
    private double crossoverRate;
    private int elitismCount;
    protected int tournamentSize;

    public GeneticAlgorithm(int populationSize, double mutationRate, double crossoverRate, int elitismCount, int tournamentSize) {
        this.populationSize = populationSize;
        this.mutationRate = mutationRate;
        this.crossoverRate = crossoverRate;
        this.elitismCount = elitismCount;
        this.tournamentSize = tournamentSize;

    }

    public int getElitismCount() {
        return elitismCount;
    }

    public Population initPopulation(int chromosomeLength) {
        Population population = new Population(this.populationSize, chromosomeLength);
        return population;
    }

    public double calcFitness(Individual individual) {
        int numSegments = 5; // Example: Divide chromosome into 5 segments
        int segmentLength = individual.getChromosomeLength() / numSegments;

        double totalFitness = 0.0;

        // Iterate over segments and calculate fitness for each
        for (int i = 0; i < numSegments; i++) {
            // Extract the segment from the chromosome
            int startIndex = i * segmentLength;
            int endIndex = (i + 1) * segmentLength;

            String segment = individual.toString().substring(startIndex, endIndex);


            // Convert the segment to an integer value
            int segmentValue = Integer.parseInt(segment, 2);

//            int lb = -100000000;
//            int ub = 100000000;
            int lb = -50;
            int ub = 50;
//          double scaledValue = lb + (double) (segmentValue / ((1 << segment.length()) - 1)) * (ub - lb);

            double scaledValue = lb + (double) (segmentValue / Math.pow(2, segmentLength)) * (ub - lb);

            // Apply fitness function to the segment (example fitness function)
            double segmentFitness = Math.pow(scaledValue, 2); // Example fitness function: Square of the segment value

            // Add segment fitness to total fitness
            totalFitness += segmentFitness;
        }

        // Store total fitness in the individual
        individual.setFitness(totalFitness);
        return totalFitness;
    }

    public void evalPopulation(Population population) {
        double populationFitness = 0;

        // Loop over population evaluating individuals and suming population
        // fitness
        for (Individual individual : population.getIndividuals()) {
            populationFitness += calcFitness(individual);
        }
        //System.out.println("populationFitness = " + populationFitness);

        population.setPopulationFitness(populationFitness);
    }


    public boolean isTerminationConditionMet(int generationCount, int maxGeneration) {
        return (generationCount >= maxGeneration);
    }

    // Implementing roulette wheel selection
    public Individual selectParent(Population population) {
        //Get individuals
        Individual individuals[] = population.getIndividuals();

        //Spin roulette wheel
        double populationFitness = population.getPopulationFitness();
        double rouletteWheelPosition = Math.random() * populationFitness;

        // Find parent
        double spinWheel = 0;
        for (Individual individual : individuals) {
            spinWheel += individual.getFitness();

            if (spinWheel >= rouletteWheelPosition) {
                return individual;
            }
        }

        return individuals[population.size() - 1];
    }

    public Individual tournamentSelectParent(Population population) {
        // Create tournament
        Population tournament = new Population(this.tournamentSize);


        // Add random individuals to the tournament
        population.shuffle();
        for (int i = 0; i < this.tournamentSize; i++) {
            Individual tournamentIndividual = population.getIndividual(i);
            tournament.setIndividual(i, tournamentIndividual);

        }
        return tournament.getFittest(tournamentSize - 1);
    }


    public Population sirMultiPointCrossover(Population population) {
        // Create new population
        Population newPopulation = new Population(population.size());
        // Iterate over pairs of parents
        for (int populationIndex = 0; populationIndex < population.size() / 2; populationIndex++) {
            int secondPopulationIndex = populationIndex + population.size() / 2;
            // Get the parents for crossover
            Individual parent1 = population.getIndividual(populationIndex);
            Individual parent2 = tournamentSelectParent(population);
//            System.out.println("\nparent1 = " + parent1.toString());
//            System.out.println("parent2 = " + parent2.toString());
            int chromosomeLength = parent1.getChromosomeLength();
//            int swapPoint1 = (int) ((Math.random() * (chromosomeLength / 3)) + 1);
//            System.out.println("swapPoint1: " + swapPoint1);
//            int swapPoint2 = (int) ((Math.random() * (chromosomeLength / 2)));
//            System.out.println("swapPoint2: " + swapPoint2);

            /*هنا لمن ضفنا نقطة التبديل الثانية الى نقطة التبديل الاولى كام ينطيني نتائج افضل**/
            int swapPoint1 = (int) ((Math.random() * (chromosomeLength / 2)) + 1);
            //System.out.println("swapPoint1: " + swapPoint1);
            int swapPoint2 = swapPoint1 + (int) ((Math.random() * (chromosomeLength / 2)));
            //System.out.println("swapPoint2: " + swapPoint2);
            // Apply crossover to this individual?
            if (this.crossoverRate > Math.random()) {
                Individual offspring1 = new Individual(parent1.getChromosomeLength());
                Individual offspring2 = new Individual(parent1.getChromosomeLength());
                // Loop over genome
                for (int geneIndex = 0; geneIndex < parent1.getChromosomeLength(); geneIndex++) {
                    // Use half of parent1's genes and half of parent2's genes
                    if (geneIndex < swapPoint1) {
                        //System.out.println("if geneIndex = " + geneIndex);
                        offspring1.setGene(geneIndex, parent1.getGene(geneIndex));
                        //System.out.print(offspring1.getGene(geneIndex));
                        offspring2.setGene(geneIndex, parent2.getGene(geneIndex));
                        //System.out.print("parent2.getGene = ");

                    } else if (geneIndex < swapPoint2) {
//                        if (geneIndex == swapPoint1) {
//                            System.out.print("**");
//                        }
                        offspring1.setGene(geneIndex, parent2.getGene(geneIndex));
                        //System.out.print(offspring1.getGene(geneIndex));
                        offspring2.setGene(geneIndex, parent1.getGene(geneIndex));
                    } else {
//                        if (geneIndex == swapPoint2) {
//                            System.out.print("**");
//                        }
                        //System.out.println("else geneIndex = " + geneIndex);
                        offspring1.setGene(geneIndex, parent1.getGene(geneIndex));
                        //System.out.print(offspring1.getGene(geneIndex));
                        offspring2.setGene(geneIndex, parent2.getGene(geneIndex));
                    }

                }




                // Add offspring to new population
                newPopulation.setIndividual(populationIndex, offspring1);
                newPopulation.setIndividual(secondPopulationIndex, offspring2);
            } else {
                // Add individual to new population without applying crossover
                newPopulation.setIndividual(populationIndex, parent1);
                newPopulation.setIndividual(secondPopulationIndex, parent2);
            }


        }
        return newPopulation;
    }

    public Population sirMutate(Population population) {
        // Initialize new population
        Population newPopulation = new Population(this.populationSize);

        //Loop over current population
        for (int populationIndex = 0; populationIndex < population.size(); populationIndex++) {

            Individual individual = population.getIndividual(populationIndex);
            for (int geneIndex = 0; geneIndex < individual.getChromosomeLength(); geneIndex++) {

                //Does this gene need mutation?
                if (this.mutationRate > Math.random()) {
                    // Get new gene
                    int newGene = 1;
                    if (individual.getGene(geneIndex) == 1) {
                        newGene = 0;
                    }
                    //Mutate gene
                    individual.setGene(geneIndex, newGene);
                }
            }

            //Add individual to population
            newPopulation.setIndividual(populationIndex, individual);

        }
        //Return mutated population
        return newPopulation;
    }


    public Population initElitismPopulation(Population population) {
        // Create elitismPopulation
        Population elitismPopulation = new Population(this.elitismCount);


//        // Add the best individuals to the elitismPopulation
        //population.sortAscPopulation();
        for (int i = 0; i < this.elitismCount; i++) {
            Individual elitismIndividual = population.getIndividual(i);
            elitismPopulation.setIndividual(i, elitismIndividual);
        }
        return elitismPopulation;
    }

    public Population elitismPopulation(Population population, Population eliti) {
        System.out.println("\n\n)*************************************");
        for (Individual individual : eliti.getIndividuals()) {
            System.out.println("Elite Individual: " + individual + ", Fitness: " + individual.getFitness());
        }
        System.out.println("*************************************");

        // Iterate through each individual in the population
        for (Individual individual : population.getIndividuals()) {
            double fitness = individual.getFitness();
            double bestFitness = eliti.getIndividual(0).getFitness();
            double secondBestFitness = eliti.getIndividual(1).getFitness();

            // Compare the fitness of the current individual with the elite individuals
            if (fitness < bestFitness) {
                eliti.setIndividual(1, eliti.getIndividual(0));
                eliti.setIndividual(0, individual);
                bestFitness = fitness;
                secondBestFitness = eliti.getIndividual(1).getFitness();
                System.out.println("Updated elites: [" + eliti.getIndividual(0).getFitness() + ", " + eliti.getIndividual(1).getFitness() + "]");
            } else if (fitness < secondBestFitness && fitness != bestFitness) {
                eliti.setIndividual(1, individual);
                secondBestFitness = fitness;
                System.out.println("Updated second best elite: " + eliti.getIndividual(1).getFitness());
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Final elites:");
        for (Individual individual : eliti.getIndividuals()) {
            System.out.println("Elite Individual: " + individual + ", Fitness: " + individual.getFitness());
        }
        System.out.println("*************************************");

        return eliti;
    }


//    public Population elitismPopulation(Population population, Population eliti) {
//
//        System.out.println("*************************************");
//        for (Individual individual : eliti.getIndividuals()) {
//            System.out.println("Elite Individual: " + individual + ", Fitness: " + individual.getFitness());
//        }
//        System.out.println("*************************************");
//        // Iterate through each individual in the population
//        for (Individual individual : population.getIndividuals()) {
//            double fitness = individual.getFitness();
//            double bestFitness = eliti.getIndividual(0).getFitness();
//            double secondBestFitness = eliti.getIndividual(1).getFitness();
//
//            // Compare the fitness of the current individual with the elite individuals
//            if (fitness < bestFitness) {
//                System.out.println("Hello");
//                // If the fitness of the current individual is lower than the fittest elite individual,
//                // shift the elite individuals and make the current individual the fittest
//                eliti.setIndividual(1, eliti.getIndividual(0));
//                eliti.setIndividual(0, individual);
//                System.out.println("Updated elites: [" + individual.getFitness() + ", " + bestFitness + "]");
//            } else if (fitness < secondBestFitness && fitness != bestFitness) {
//                eliti.setIndividual(1, individual);
//                System.out.println("Updated second best elite: " + individual.getFitness());
//            }
//        }
//        return eliti;
//    }

    public void updatePopulationWithElite(Population population, Population elitism) {
//        Random rand = new Random();
//
//        for (int i = 0; i < elitism.size(); i++) {
//            Individual individual = elitism.getIndividual(i);
//            int index = rand.nextInt(population.size());
//            population.setIndividual(index, individual);
//
//        }


    }


    public Population elitismPopulation2(Population population, Population eliti) {

        // Iterate through each individual in the population
        for (Individual individual : population.getIndividuals()) {
            // Compare the fitness of the current individual with the elite individuals

            if (individual.getFitness() < eliti.getIndividual(0).getFitness()) {
                // If the fitness of the current individual is lower than the fittest elite individual,
                // shift the elite individuals and make the current individual the fittest
                eliti.setIndividual(2, eliti.getIndividual(1));
                eliti.setIndividual(1, eliti.getIndividual(0));
                eliti.setIndividual(0, individual);
            } else if (individual.getFitness() < eliti.getIndividual(1).getFitness() && individual.getFitness() != eliti.getIndividual(0).getFitness()) {
                // If the fitness of the current individual is lower than the second fittest elite individual,
                // replace the second fittest with the current individual
                eliti.setIndividual(2, eliti.getIndividual(1));
                eliti.setIndividual(1, eliti.getIndividual(0));
            } else if (individual.getFitness() < eliti.getIndividual(2).getFitness() && individual.getFitness() != eliti.getIndividual(0).getFitness() && individual.getFitness() != eliti.getIndividual(1).getFitness()) {
                // If the fitness of the current individual is lower than the second fittest elite individual,
                // replace the second fittest with the current individual
                eliti.setIndividual(2, individual);
            }
        }

        // Print the updated elite individuals
//        for (Individual individual : eliti.getIndividuals()) {
//            System.out.println("Elite Individual: " + individual + ", Fitness: " + individual.getFitness());
//        }

        return eliti;
    }

    public Population mergePopulation(Population population, Population eliti) {
        int sizeOfNewPopulation = this.elitismCount + this.populationSize;


        Population mergedPopulation = new Population(sizeOfNewPopulation);
        for (int i = 0; i < this.populationSize; i++) {
            Individual individual = population.getIndividual(i);
            mergedPopulation.setIndividual(i, individual);
        }

        int j = 0;
        for (int i = this.populationSize; i < sizeOfNewPopulation; i++) {
            Individual individual = eliti.getIndividual(j);
            mergedPopulation.setIndividual(i, individual);
            j++;
        }

        return mergedPopulation;
    }


}





I have tried to trace the code but there is one bug where my data get overflow by someting I don't know

Given the amount of code you posted it is hard to debug this just by looking at it. You should definitely work on getting your debugger to work and then step through your application to see where it starts to get wrong. Doing a spot check it seems elite selection might be off, e.g. when merging populations you put the elites last but when extracting them you pull the first individuals (the sort has been commented but you'd normally want to sort to get the elites - not necessarily in place but a copy of the population/array of individuals).

Btw, if elites are preserved over generations that doesn't mean offspring or mutations won't generate better individuals (that's your goal after all) so having elites with higher fitness after several iterations shouldn't be surprising. Could you elaborate on what bothers you and what you would expect?

Another observation: fitness is normally defined as a positive value which is better the higher it gets. Hence the fitness < bestFitness is a little odd. I'd replace that check and update loop with creating a copy of the population's individuals array, sorting that in descending order (highest fitness first) and then taking the first x elements (in your case it seems x = 2).

Thank you Thomas for your valuable reply, but as I mentioned the issue is that after some iteration the preserved Eliti solution got lost and changed with something I don't know from where :(

Sorry for putting this much of code, it's for reference.

Very poor title, please rewrite ti summarize the actual technical issue.

It's been a while since I worked with genetic algorithms but let me share some general observations (given the amount of code you posted I might have missed something though):
General approach
While there are multiple different approaches to GA the basic philosophy would be "survival of the fittest". That means you'd generate more individuals than can fit into a population, sort by fitness and cull the rest (that's where "survival" comes into the picture).
Your code basically replaces 2 parents with 2 offspring in case of a crossover "event". However, the offspring might be worse than their parents so you'd lose some better solutions and your solutions might start to dither or even deteriorate.
Normally, you'd add the offspring to the population which makes it bigger, then eventually sort by fitness and then remove excess elements to establish the target population size. This might get rid of the parents or the offspring, depending on whose fitness is worse.
Mutation would come in before the sort and cull step to avoid getting stuck in local optima but the mutants might also just be new individuals so you don't lose already good solutions by changing them in place.
That means your population might look like this right before the sort and cull:
+---------------------+-----------+---------+
| Original population | Offspring | Mutants |
+---------------------+-----------+---------+

Selection of survivors (or elites)
Generally fitness is considered a positive value, i.e. the higher the better. That means that elitismPopulation() seems to select the worst individuals instead due to checks like fitness < bestFitness.
Your implementation seems to sort in some cases and not in others.
In general I'd suggest you make that consistent, e.g. by keeping the population sorted or sorting it after each generation. Position of an individual inside a population normally isn't important other than it defines its fitness compared to the others. So I'd do something like this:

Init population with random individuals
Sort population based on descending fitness
for each generation:

generate offspring by generating crossovers of the original population (already sorted)
add the offspring to the end of the population (breaks the sorting)
generate mutants based on original population and offspring (sort before doing this if mutation rate is based on elitism)
add mutants to the end of the population
sort the population based on fitness
shrink population to target size



Elitism
There are several approaches on how elitism can be used so let me add a few suggestions:

Elites are ensured survival of the current generation, even if offspring and mutants might be better
Parents are selected based on elitism, i.e. elites have a higher likelihood of producing offspring
Elites might have lower/higher mutation rates


Thank you, the problem was that the object did not change due to my mistake in copying the reference
